# Can I say "I speak Chinese as well as Spanish"?

Tags: word-usage

> I speak Chinese **as well as** Spanish.

I want to say that my Chinese and Spanish are equally strong. So please help me out with this. I think it's weird to say speak "as well as". I don't know if there are other better expressions.

Comment: Suggestion: I think you need to add your proposed **sentence** completely. I think it would make your question more readable!

Comment: If you are fluent in Chinese (Cantonese or Mandarin, by the way?) and Spanish, say so. If not, indicate your level of fluency in *some* way by saying something like, "I am reasonably fluent in both spoken and written Mandarin and Spanish, in addition to English." There is nothing wrong with saying "My Chinese and Spanish are equally strong." By the way, these are skills that many employers are actively looking for. Good for you! Just flesh out your question as @Cardinal suggested by giving an example of what you want to write and the context; for instance, to add to your resume.

Comment: “I speak Chinese and Urdu equally well.”  (I changed it to make it true for me.  I can't speak either at all.)

Comment: "As well as" is okay here.

Answer (score 41):

*I speak Chinese **as well as** Spanish* is "ambiguous", in that it could mean either of...

> 1: *I speak Chinese **and also** I speak Spanish*
>    2: *I speak Chinese **as competently as** I speak Spanish*

Context will normally make it obvious which sense is intended. #1 above is probably more *likely*, but you can easily force the sense of #2 using something like ***just*** as well as, for example.

Comment: "I speak Chinese as well as I speak Spanish" is a lot more natural if you want to remove ambiguity. Or "I speak Chinese and Spanish equally well"

Comment: @Aurast: For reasons that aren't obvious to me, I associate *I [v1] as well as I [v2]* much more strongly with ironic usages (it's well-known / obvious that I do [v2] badly). But that's an unlikely meaning with ***just***.

Comment: "I speak Chinese *just as well* as I speak Spanish" is another possible way to remove the ambiguity.

Comment: The word *ambiguous* shouldn't be in quotes, because you are using it in its literal sense. Additionally, I find this to be more natural than your example rectification #1: "I speak Chines and I also speak Spanish" (moving *also* one word later). Thoughts?

Comment: @ErikE: Cheek! :) If I decide to put "ambiguous" in "scare quotes" it's your responsibility as a reader to make the effort to understand *why* I did that - not lambaste me for a supposed error. (To save you the trouble on this occasion, I'll just say that when I wrote the first line I was anticipating my closing paragraph which would point out that in practice it's usually *not* ambiguous. :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers It wasn't my intention to lambaste you. I simply found it to be clearly ambiguous, myself, before ever reading your answer. I think that to use scare quotes for English language learners is to be subtle in a way that they are likely to miss. I see no need for taking a clever tack to expose meaning—just explain in plain English. You could say more plainly: *The sentence "I speak Chinese as well as Spanish" is ambiguous as written, especially out of any context*. Thus, no scare quotes are needed since you explicated instead of implicated. These are language *learners*, here.

Comment: @ErikE: There simply isn't much *point* in saying a string of text without context has any particular meaning (or plurality of meanings). As implied earlier, the context might make it *completely* unambiguous that the intended sense is a facetious *I **don't** speak Chinese, any more than I speak Spanish.* Seriously though - it's obvious *you* found my orthography distracting (for what I consider lamentable reasons that I think you should work on overcoming), but I really can't buy the argument that this is likely to be a problem for my primary target audience here.

Comment: Thank you for raising my awareness about personally lamentable and serious life-interfering issues which emphatically require immediate remediation. I will take your comprehensive, razor keen assessment of my whole person with all seriousness by seeking the long-term help of a licensed psychotherapist at the first opportunity. I was under the lamentable, false impression that I was only trying to assist you in making your answer the best possible one it could be; I see now that I was merely viciously excoriating you due to my deeply rooted emotional problems and oversensitivity. Turnabout ifp.

Comment: One more thing: The question is *itself* stating the phrase outside of any context. Thus it is legitimate to answer in the *given* context (of no context) and then speak about real-world contexts. When I read the question in *Hot Network Questions*, it was also out of context and was intensely ambiguous to me. Thus, in a very real way, there is, to me, quite a lot of *point* in saying a string of text without context has a plurality of meanings, if only to provide a different kind of context for the questioner. I find your reaction weirdly and knowingly pricklish, though can't fathom why.

Comment: @ErikE: Mostly I'm just being light-hearted (as indicated by initial **Cheek!** :) But yes - there is an element of pricklishness, since in effect you're questioning my linguistic competence. By the same token, I'd be a bit irritated if you (or anyone else) responded to *this* comment by pointing out that "pricklishness" isn't a valid word (because it doesn't appear in any dictionaries, which may or may not be true; I haven't checked exhaustively). What I mean is that like any competent native speaker, I'm perfectly happy with how I speak and write.

Comment: I had no idea what you meant by *Cheek!*. For all I knew, you were saying *I* was being cheeky. Criticizing word choice of a comment with a native speaker is a very different thing from finding a potential flaw in an *answer* intended for a non-native speaker. That you took my comment as questioning your competence seems the real problem, here, because if you truly were perfectly happy with how you speak and write you would not bristle so at comments from a faceless stranger on the Internet. I personally doubt a non-native has the knowledge to understand the subtleties of ironic quote usage.

Comment: P.S. Puzzled by your stance on *pricklishness*: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/pricklish

Comment: @ErikE: The point about ***pricklishness*** was simply that I'm guessing that exact form probably won't be listed in any dictionaries. But certainly the cut-down version of OED online includes [***prickliness***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/prickly?q=prickliness#prickly__10), and I expect several others will too.

Comment: Though when you look at the definition of *pricklish* it says a variant of *prickly*, thus *pricklishness* is the parallel form of *prickliness*. Simple! Not all inflections are in the dictionary, but words can be nonetheless valid.

Comment: @ErikE: Would that it were so simple! Pedantry aside, ***pricklishness*** is fine (it's been recorded hundreds of times in Google Books). But it doesn't acquire that status just because it's a "parallel form" of ***prickliness***. If that were the case, ***bossishness***, say, would be an equally acceptable alternative to ***bossiness***. I've never encountered the first of those before, and probably won't again in the future, but if I *did* accept it as a credible usage, I'd interpret it very specifically in the context of *employers*, not bossy people in general.

Comment: Is *bossish* in the OED as an alternate for *bossy*?

Comment: @ErikE: Not a chance! I can read the actual context in [half-a-dozen written instances](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22bossish%22), of which only one is clearly the specific "like a boss / employer" sense I referred to *(affable and bossish)*. But to all intents and purposes, each instance is a one-off "nonce word" coinage, not the normal reuse of existing symbolic tokens (i.e. - "words").

Comment: I'm tired. Be well. Sorry for helping.

Answer (score 10):

To announce that you speak both languages, you can simply say: '**I speak Chinese and Spanish**'. But to announce that you speak them equally well, the construction alters to: '**I speak Chinese and Spanish equally well**'.

To native English speakers, the latter is still ambiguous, but for a different reason. It can mean 'I speak them both well', certainly; but it *can* also mean 'I speak them both, equally badly'. The fact that a person has equal ability in each language tells us nothing about his *level* of competence, only that it is equal in each case.

An unambiguous construction is '**I speak Chinese and Spanish fluently**'. Avoidance of the comparative term *equally* is a way of avoiding a comparison between the two: by substituting an absolute term, *fluently*, in place of a comparative term.

In English, comparatives are a common cause of ambiguity.

This is especially true of written English, where there are no verbal clues of stress and intonation to clarify what the intended meaning is.

For example, "I speak Chinese as well as I speak Spanish" can be interpreted as meaning "I speak Chinese *about as well* as I speak Spanish", because the phrase 'as well as' can mean 'as (in)competently as'. It does not solely mean *also*, it can mean *at what level of competence*; and in point of fact it is just as ambiguous as *equally*.

Comment: I disagree that "equally well" is ambiguous. "Equally well" _strongly_ implies "to the same good standard", not just "to the same standard, whatever that might be."

Comment: Is there a possible ambiguity for "I speak Chinese and Spanish fluently" to be mistaken for "I speak Chinese. I speak Spanish fluently."?

Comment: Nice answer. Could I suggest "I speak both Chinese and Spanish fluently" would make it clear that you don't speak "Chinese, and Spanish fluently". A slight spoken pause before the "and" could still confuse the listener.

Comment: "Equally well" could be used sarcastic, or in humour, but I would add "which is not at all" to avoid confusion. Unless I want to cause confusion. I would also put the language that I'm less likely to know last. If I meet an average white person in Texas, there's a reasonable chance they might speak a bit of Spanish and it's less likely they speak Chinese, so that person might say in humour "I speak Spanish equally well as Chinese", but not the other way round.

Comment: My experience is that, with spoken English, comedians often employ exactly this form of construction, intentionally, in order to generate humour out of ambiguity. Depending where the stress is placed when speaking, almost any sentence we can come up with is capable of being rendered ambiguous. For example, iHiD inserted one comma into my example, and thereby changed the meaning of my sentence, which can also be achieved during speech by pausing in the same place, whether the pause is intentional or accidental. In English, almost any sentence, especially taken out of context, can be ambiguous.

Answer (score 4):

What you're saying now technically does communicate what you want to say, but you should say:

> I speak Chinese as well as I speak Spanish.

or,

> I speak Chinese and Spanish well.

What you're trying to say now can - and probably will - be interpreted as:

> I speak Chinese and Spanish.

Answer (score 1):

"I speak Chinese as well as Spanish." Is a perfectly acceptable construction. You could even add "I speak Chinese as well as Spanish fluently" or any other adjective besides 'fluently' really.

You could even say "I speak Chinese and Spanish" without the 'as well as'.

Comment: It's acceptable in the US (at least) because we know what that construct is supposed to mean. But it's ambiguous without benefit. Per the question, it doesn't inform how well the languages are spoken, nor does it denote equality of skill.

Answer (score 1):

Your original suggests more that you speak them both than that you speak them equally well (though it's ambiguous). With the right timing/emphasis/tone on "as well as" would help to convey the intended meaning (to convey it via something more like "as well-as Spanish" rather than "as well ... as Spanish").

However, I'd say it this way:

"I speak Chinese as well as I do Spanish" (which is true for me, since I speak only a few words of either -- I speak them both extremely poorly)

Answer (score 1):

How about next phrase.

> My Chinese and Spanish are at the same level.
>
> My Chinese is at the same level as my Spanish.

Comment: My Chinese and Spanish are at the same level.

Answer (score 0):

As a native English speaker, I understand you if you were to say "I speak Chinese as well as Spanish."

Personally, it is easier and more natural to say "I speak both Chinese and Spanish." to demonstrate competence in the languages, or "I am fluent in both Chinese and Spanish." to demonstrate mastery of them.

Generally, shorter sentances are better, and "As well as" is longer than "Both".

Answer (score 0):

I think it's good to use "as good as",

So you could say:

> I speak Chinese as good as Spanish.